# 2013 Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Web Applications' [third moderator election](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/election/3) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

[image: jonsca]

He'll be joining [the existing crew](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank him for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice as he learns the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/election/3), or [view the results online](http://www.opavote.org/results/6549965518143488/0).

Comment: @jonsca congratulations :)

Comment: @Fogest Thank you, and congrats on a great finish!

Comment: Congratulations and condolences, @jonsca.

Comment: @Krampus Thanks! (And thanks? :) )

Answer (score 8):

Congratulations, [jonsca](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/11175/jonsca). It's great to have you onboard the Mod team.

Comment: Thanks!  Happy to be a part of it.

Comment: Yup :) Congrats @jonsca, you deserved it

Answer (score 5):

**5 months later...** As someone who can pick an argument with anyone I am mightily surprised never to have had any cause to quibble over any of jonsca’s judgement calls  (how tricky some of those are!) He’s even been right when I’ve been wrong! Also, in my limited time here, he seems to have done pretty much all of the moderation on his own, except for Sathya. Very much appreciated – and thanks also to those 120 or so voters who knew a good thing when they saw it.